# cant get json data, the under categories ones

Tags: jquery, json, getjson

lemme discribe the situation, there is a json data that gives the flight information with different airlines, there are prices, dates, everything, but i cant get the information i need in the way i want. thus here it comes:

i have another newbie question about json datas callbacks, so far i could get with the help of Yograj Gupta the list of airlines names from json list data, with this structure type: http://vteem.net/json.json and here is the code:

```
$.getJSON("http://api.anywayanyday.com/api/NewRequest/?Route=2406MOWLON&AD=1&CN=0&CS=E&Partner=testapic&_Serialize=JSON&callback=?", function(data) {
        var code=data.Id;
        $.getJSON("http://api.anywayanyday.com/api/Fares/?R="+code+"&V=Matrix&VB=true&L=ru&_Serialize=JSON&callback=?", function(data) {
            var items = [];
            $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                if(val && (typeof val == 'object' || typeof val == 'array')){
                    if(key == "Airlines"){
                        var airlineNames = [];
                        for(var x in val)
                            airlineNames.push(val[x].Name);
                        items.push(airlineNames.join('<br/>'));
                    }
                }
            });
            $('<div/>', {
                'id': 'airlines',
                html: items.join('')
            }).appendTo('#data');
        });
    });
```

i want to get the total amount value inside each airlines row, plus, is it possible to sort them by the total amount prices values?

thank you all for the help, i really appreciate it!

**UPDATE OF CODE:**

```
$.getJSON("http://api.anywayanyday.com/api/NewRequest/?Route=2406MOWLON&AD=1&CN=0&CS=E&Partner=testapic&_Serialize=JSON&callback=?", function(data) {
        var code=data.Id;
        $.getJSON("http://api.anywayanyday.com/api/Fares/?R="+code+"&V=Matrix&VB=true&L=ru&_Serialize=JSON&callback=?", function(data) {
            var items = [];
            $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                if(val && (typeof val == 'object' || typeof val == 'array')){
                    if(key == "Airlines"){
                        var airlineNames = [];
                        for(var x in val)
                            airlineNames.push(val[x].Name);
                        items.push(airlineNames.join('<br/>'));

                        $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                            if(val && (typeof val == 'object' || typeof val == 'array')){
                                if(key == "FaresFull"){
                                    var totalAmounts = [];
                                    for(var y in val)
                                        totalAmounts.push(val[y].TotalAmount);
                                    items.push(totalAmounts.join('<br/>'));
                                }
                            }
                        });                     
                    }
                }
            });
            $('<div/>', {
                'id': 'airlines',
                html: items.join('')
            }).appendTo('#data');
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't exactly understand what you are going to do... But you have some mistakes in your script. The main one is: `$.each(data, function(key, val) {` . Data passed from this jsonp request is not an array. It's object. This object has property : `Airlines`. So, if you want to iterate throw all airline you should use data.Airlines. If the main task is to print out all airlines names this script will work:

```
$.getJSON("http://api.anywayanyday.com/api/NewRequest/?Route=2406MOWLON&AD=1&CN=0&CS=E&Partner=testapic&_Serialize=JSON&callback=?", function(data) {
    var code=data.Id;
    $.getJSON("http://api.anywayanyday.com/api/Fares/?R="+code+"&V=Matrix&VB=true&L=ru&_Serialize=JSON&callback=?", function(data) {
        var airlineNames = [];
        $.each(data.Airlines, function() {                  
                airlineNames.push(this.Name);
        });
        $('<div/>', {
            'id': 'airlines',
            html: airlineNames.join(',')
        }).appendTo('#data');
    });
});​
```

Hope it'll help you.

**UPDATE:**

No problem) But the main issue in you code is that second time you iterate in all json data again(loop in loop). It's not the best solution. I've written some demo for you. Please check it: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ErJNA/3/) . As I understood you requirements it should make the job...
Code from demo:

```
$.getJSON("http://api.anywayanyday.com/api/NewRequest/?Route=2406MOWLON&AD=1&CN=0&CS=E&Partner=testapic&_Serialize=JSON&callback=?", function(data) {
var code=data.Id;
$.getJSON("http://api.anywayanyday.com/api/Fares/?R="+code+"&V=Matrix&VB=true&L=ru&_Serialize=JSON&callback=?", function(data) {
    var pricesForEachAirline = [];
    $.each(data.Airlines, function() { 
        var item = { name : this.Name, prices : []};            
        for(var y in this.FaresFull)
        {
            item.prices.push(this.FaresFull[y].TotalAmount);
        }
           pricesForEachAirline.push(item);
    });
    $.each(pricesForEachAirline , function(){
        $('#data').append(this.name, this.prices.join(',')).append('</br>')
    }); 
});
```

});​

Comment: thank you for the answer, but my code is working fine (and urs doesnt) but not the way i want it to work, please pay attetion to the structure of json file. btw, i want to get total amounts from this json http://api.anywayanyday.com/api/Fares/?R=ec6r167G4j3826&V=Matrix&VB=true&L=ru&_Serialize=JSON&callback=?

Comment: so, you want to get total amount for each of air line? For example:'Air baltic' = 3882 . Am I right?

Comment: yes! exactly, i want to get each total amount for each airline, as far as i understand from json data, there are several of total amounts, i updated my code, but still cant get the total amount, just list of airlines comes

Comment: please, help me once again! i have the similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12616103/cant-get-data-from-json-list