# cant get data from json list

Tags: jquery, json, jsonp, getjson

so far i made a list of airlines and their prices for each flight, and now i want to get all the information about these flights from json list, any way here are the functions:

first function works fine:

```
function show_airlines() {
    $.getJSON("http://api.anywayanyday.com/api/NewRequest/?Route=2406MOWLON&AD=1&CN=0&CS=E&Partner=testapic&_Serialize=JSON&callback=?", function(data) {
        var id=data.Id;
        $('#search_id').attr('rel',id);
        $.getJSON("http://api.anywayanyday.com/api/Fares/?R="+id+"&V=Matrix&VB=true&L=ru&_Serialize=JSON&callback=?", function(data) {
            var pricesForEachAirline = [];
            $.each(data.Airlines, function() { 
                var item = { name : this.Name, prices : [], code: this.Code, airid: []};            
                for(var y in this.FaresFull)
                {
                    item.prices.push(this.FaresFull[y].TotalAmount);
                    item.airid.push(this.FaresFull[y].FareId);
                }
                pricesForEachAirline.push(item);
            });
            $.each(pricesForEachAirline , function(){
                $('#airlines').append('<a href="javascript://" onclick="show_flights('+ this.airid +');">'+ this.name +'</a>').append('</br>');
                $('#prices').append(this.prices.join(',')).append('</br>');
            }); 
        });
    });
}
```

The Second one doesnt work properly...

```
function show_flights() {
    var id=$('#search_id').attr('rel');
    var list = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
    $.getJSON("http://api.anywayanyday.com/api/Fares/?R="+id+"&V=Matrix&VB=true&L=ru&_Serialize=JSON&callback=?", function(data) {
        var dataForEachFlight = [];
        $.each(data.Airlines, function() { 
            for(var x in this.FaresFull)
            {
                if(this.FaresFull[x].FareId in list) 
                { 
                    var flight = { from : [], to : []}
                    for(var y in this.FaresFull.Directions.Segments.Trips) 
                    {
                        flight.from.push(this.FaresFull.Directions.Segments.Trips.Departure[y].AirportCode);
                        flight.to.push(this.FaresFull.Directions.Segments.Trips.Arrival[y].AirportCode);
                    }
                    dataForEachFlight.push(flight);
                }
            }
        });
        $.each(dataForEachFlight , function(){
            $('#flights').append(this.from.join(',')).append('</br>');
        });
    });
}
```

so when i click on the airline link i want to get the information about it's flights only, but it gives out the mistake like: **this.FaresFull.Directions is undefined** and as an example of json from which i want to get all the information: http://vteem.net/json.json (this is just example, the original u can get from link function)

thank you all for the help, i really appreciate it!

**FUNCTION 2 UPDATE**

```
function show_flights() {
var id=$('#search_id').attr('rel');
var list = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
$.getJSON('http://api.anywayanyday.com/api/Fares/?R='+id+'&V=Matrix&VB=true&L=ru&_Serialize=JSON&callback=?', function(data) {
    var dataForEachFlight = [];
    $.each(data.Airlines, function() {
        for(var a in this.FaresFull)
        {
            for(var b in this.FaresFull[a].FareId)
            {    
                if(this.FaresFull[a].FareId[b] in list) 
                { 
                    var flight = { from : [], to : []};
                    for(var c in this.FaresFull[a].Directions[0].Segments[0].Trips) 
                    {                
                        flight.from.push(this.FaresFull[a].Directions[0].Segments[0].Trips[c].Departure.AirportCode);
                        flight.to.push(this.FaresFull[a].Directions[0].Segments[0].Trips[c].Arrival.AirportCode);
                    }
                    dataForEachFlight.push(flight);
                }
            }
        }
    });
    $.each(dataForEachFlight , function(){
        $('#flights').append(this.from.join(',')).append('</br>');
    });
});
```

}

try #12

Now it gets the data, but it repeats too much :) some mistake in for() clauses.

Comment: Maybe it actually *is* `undefinined` and you just need to check it's value before hand?

Comment: That JSON in the file you linked is not proper JSON. `({})` will not work, there will be no properties within this object, especially not the one you want. Your JSON needs to be presented as `[{}]`.

Comment: @DrColossos yes it is undefined because i wrote the code wrongly, that is why i ask for the help

Comment: @Ohgodwhy no it works fine, at least with the first function

Comment: So, have you sold this problem?

Comment: @AlexeyBychkov solved, or sold? )) no i didnt solve this problem, or this is not for sale, u can't actually earn from this type of script..

Comment: @venom solved ofc, sorry) Maybe I'll help...just a second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I've modified our last [solution](http://jsfiddle.net/ErJNA/3/) . But result is not final, it just shows you the way to cope with you issue(it prints out all pricess and all connected departures and arrivals airport codes for each of airline). You can find demo [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/ErJNA/8/).
Code:

```
$.getJSON("http://api.anywayanyday.com/api/NewRequest/?Route=2406MOWLON&AD=1&CN=0&CS=E&Partner=testapic&_Serialize=JSON&callback=?", function(data) {
var code=data.Id;
$.getJSON("http://api.anywayanyday.com/api/Fares/?R="+code+"&V=Matrix&VB=true&L=ru&_Serialize=JSON&callback=?", function(data) {
    var pricesForEachAirline = [];
    $.each(data.Airlines, function() { 

        var item = { name : this.Name, infos: []};            

        $.each(this.FaresFull, function()
        {
            var info = {departures:[], arrivals:[]}; 
            info.price=this.TotalAmount;
            $.each(this.Directions, function(){
                $.each(this.Segments, function(){
            $.each(this.Trips, function()
            {
                info.departures.push(this.Departure.AirportCode);
                info.arrivals.push(this.Arrival.AirportCode);
            });
                   });
        });
            item.infos.push(info);
        });
           pricesForEachAirline.push(item);
    });
    $.each(pricesForEachAirline , function(){
        $('#data').append(this.name+":").append('</br>');
        $.each(this.infos, function(){
            $('#data').append(this.price+"&nbsp; DEPARTURES:").append(this.departures.join(',')).append("&nbsp; ARRIVALS:").append(this.arrivals.join(',')).append("</br></br>");
        });
    });

});});​
```

Hope, it will be usefull for you!)

Comment: ofcourse it will help me )) u're json god! ) thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, and didn't test it out myself but could it be that you just forgot the index **x** of your **FaresFull** element?

I mean, shouldn't your code always call *this.FaresFull[**x**]* and become this:

```
for(var x in this.FaresFull)
{    
    if(this.FaresFull[x].FareId in list) 
    { 
        var flight = { from : [], to : []};
        // for testing only first Directions/Segments array element taken 
        for(var y in this.FaresFull[x].Directions[0].Segments[0].Trips) 
        {                
            flight.from.push(this.FaresFull[x].Directions[0].Segments[0].Trips[y].Departure.AirportCode);
            flight.to.push(this.FaresFull[x].Directions[0].Segments[0].Trips[y].Arrival.AirportCode);
        }
        dataForEachFlight.push(flight);
    }
}
```

**edit:** corrected code, see also http://jsfiddle.net/LZ8wN/2/

**edit2:** 
You might want to try this alternative way to traverse the arrays.
Note that I added a semicolon to the end of your flight declaration and asssignment.

```
$.each(data.Airlines, function() { 
    var flight = { from : [], to : []};
    $.each(this.FaresFull,function(w) {
        if(this.FareId in list) 
        {
            $.each(this.Directions,function(x) {
                $.each(this.Segments,function(y) {
                    $.each(this.Trips,function(z) {
                        flight.from.push(this.Departure.AirportCode);
                        flight.to.push(this.Arrival.AirportCode);
                    });
                    dataForEachFlight.push(flight);
                });
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Can't see anything wrong then.. it's over my head. Do you still get an error **this.FaresFull.Directions is undefined** or rather **this.FaresFull[x].Directions is undefined** now? The error should indicate the index number now.

Comment: sorry, now there is no mistake, but still the function seems to stop after this row: `$.getJSON('http://api.anywayanyday.com/api/Fares/?R='+id+'&V=Matrix&VB=true&L=ru&_Serialize=JSON&callback=?', function(data) {`

Comment: as far as i understand, the directions and segments, are just like folders, but they are not arrays, u can see it from json example: http://vteem.net/json.json or maybe not )) im a newbie in json and arrays

Comment: sorry, I can't access that url from here I looked at your actual generated json . Since Directions, Segments and Trips are arrays you can give it a try to just call the first element like this: _this.FaresFull[x].Directions[0].Segments[0].Trips[y].Departure.AirportCode]_  (and apply the same in the for statement and the Arrival).. if this doesn't work let's call upon some off the real Stackoverflow json gods...

Comment: wait )) i didnt notice it, but it takes data only from first flight, not from all of them, because, when i click on another airline it appends the same values

Comment: yes, the fiddle uses lookup for FareId 81 for demonstration purposes only. Also for testing, only the first element of the Directions array is taken _this.FaresFull[x].Directions[0].Segments[y].Trips[z].Departure.AirportCode_ You'll need a fourth loop.. (I'll look at the fiddle later, probably using $.each makes it cleaner..)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17290/discussion-between-venom-and-aardvark71)